# check if one of multiple values exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

For array with single values like

```
array(2) {
  ["blue"]=>
  int(0)
  ["red"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

I use this code

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('blue',$array))
{
    echo "jo";
}
?>
```

But what code do I need to use for arrays like this

```
array(2) {
  ["yellow blue"]=>
  int(0)
  ["red white"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

to check if blue exists?

Comment: Do you want to check if the text blu exist in the key?

Comment: yes, check for 'yellow blue' works but not the check for blue only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take:

```
if(preg_grep('/blue/', array_keys($array))) { echo 'found'; }
```

Or if you want to get them:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/blue/', array_keys($array));
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I saw other comments, you have to adjust the pattern if you don't want `greenblue` etc. You have to be specific about what you want.

Comment: your second code works but the first one looks better but the page isn't loading with it, is there may be an error in the code?

Comment: Yes, edited. But these are examples not copy paste for you.  Does your editor not have some syntax highlighting?

Comment: No, which editor would you recommand? Your code works great :D

Comment: Depends.  If you're serious about coding projects then check out an IDE (eclipse, netbeans, aptana, scores of others).  Notepad++ is a good text editor for windows that has syntax highlighting.  Not sure about Mac, but I use Linux and most if not all editors have some mode for programming of popular languages.

Answer (score 2):

```
$partialKey = 'blue';
$byPartialKey = function ($key) use ($partialKey) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $key);
    return in_array($partialKey, $parts);
};

$result = array_filter (array_keys($input), $byPartialKey);
```

`$result` now contains all keys, that somehow contains `$partialKey`.

Comment: Thanks but how do I echo something if blue is found?

Comment: If $result if empty then echo "is there" or else "not there" right?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller With `echo`. Actually I don't know, whats the matter now. --- `echo $result ? 'one or more "blue" found' : 'No "blue" found';`

Answer (score 2):

you can do using regular expression

```
search='blue';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if (preg_match('~'.$search.'~i',$key)) {
    echo "jo";
 }
}
```

The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct
word "blue" is matched, and not a word partial like "bluegreen"

```
search='blue';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if (preg_match('/\b'.$search.'\b/i',$key)) {
    echo "jo";
 }
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Thought of this too, but this also hits for example `yellow bluegreen`. Don't know, if this is an issue now, but changing requirements can make that an issue later, so I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: You have to define the regular expression you want, only the word blue, o that contain blue in the string

Comment: I tried $search='blue';
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
     if (preg_match('/\b'.$search.'\b/i',$key) {
    echo "jo";
 }
} but the page isn't loading

Comment: It was missing a close parenthesis in the `IF`, answer updated

Comment: Now it works too and is great for exact match. But for now i don't need exact match so I accepted AbraCadaver's solution

Comment: it's fine, but how @AbraCadaver says you need to use an ide, to see this kind of error, the ide makes your life easy

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function subkey_exists($string, $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $sub_keys = explode(" ", $key);
        if(in_array($string,$sub_keys)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[edit]

updated to your requirements

Comment: See my commet at Emilios answer: This also covers `yell bluegreen`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another `array_filter` solution :

```
<?php
function find_keys_like($key, $array) {
    return array_filter(array_keys($array), function($k) use (&$key) {
        return strpos($k, $key) > -1;
    });
}
function array_has_key_like($key, $array) {
    return count(find_keys_like($key, $array)) > 0;
}

//test
$a = array('blue' => 1, 'yellow blue' => 2, 'green' => 3);
print_r(find_keys_like('blue', $a));
echo 'blue exists ? ' . (array_has_key_like('blue', $a) ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
/** result :
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => yellow blue
)
blue exists ? yes
*/
```